# making my PC a proxy router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy

I don't know if "Proxy Router" is the term, but this is what I want to do: 
There are three PC users bugging me and we all share the same internet WiFi connection via a wireless router.

What I want to do is keep my PC in between and filter their requests to the router, since I own the connection, so that I would be the one to decide whose request and what requests are permitted.

Comment: I sure hope you though very hard about the privacy implications. Depending on local laws you might even have to establish a proper contract if you want to intercept and filter their data.

Comment: @DanielB , just experiment sort of stuff, and they're no outsiders so most probably it's okay.

Comment: What are you hoping to actually achieve? A pop-up dialog with Yes/No for every single connection they try to make? A tad over-ambitious, if so. You'd never clear all the dialogs. Yesterday, my gateway peaked at 280 concurrent connections - not a busy day by any means. It also filtered out several thousand spurious or malformed packets - none of these were malicious, just 'in error' for one reason or another. Unless you are planning to set up some type of 'parental control' structure, managed sensibly by appropriate software, then give up now.

Comment: @Tetsujin , not over every connection, but a filter mechanism to stop them searching for some stuffs, like, say they over watch vampire stuffs a lot, so, preventing every results containing their search for vampire, and instead returning a no search results found to them. But, vampire is just a variable, you could block anything with it, like block adult stuffs, block late night surfing. And once a way has been found, then, there's always a way to automate it. :-)

Comment: You need a parental control package, then.